# Bootstrap: How to control the height of each grid row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap's grid to align an input, a button and an alert message.
However, I found the height of alert message is much higher than that of button and input. 
Is there a way to make the height of all elements in grid consistent? 
Here is example and code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rktg0L2w/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="alert alert-success"> Result:  </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Derek

Comment: Making inputs as big as Alert wouldn't look good. You could either make Alert div height small or you set both vertical align.

Answer (score 0):

Alert div isn't made to place inside your views. It has it's own padding and margin. It is usually put at the top of page.

However if you want to put it inside your view. You could either make it small by removing padding or make your view vertical align.

I made both alternatives in this https://jsfiddle.net/rktg0L2w/1/

1) For small alter div that matches your input change padding:

```
.alert-small{
    padding: 7px;
}
```

2) In case you want to make both input and alter vertical align:

Place `vcenter` class on your `row` div and `alert-large` on your alter `div`.

```
.vcenter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.alert-large{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has its own standard, however you can change the code by edit the raw bootstrap css or override the bootstrap css code. For example :

[padding is the problem in your case, click here for 1st picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKTFJ.png)

[hola, click here for 2nd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HsBV.png)

However, you can make it specific by adding new class or with your superpower and your handsomeness tho

---

t(.__.t) my life